# Intro.js Issue where intro.js is not firing

Tags: intro.js

I've added the intro.js and introjs.css file and followed the instructions for installation. When I click the Start link at the top of my site, nothing happens.

I've added an alert popup so I know the helpme section is getting called, but I can't figure out why intro.js isn't firing.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#helpme").click(function() {
    //alert("IntroJS");
introJs().setOptions({
  steps: [{
    title: 'Math Tutoring Help',
    intro: 'Start here for help'
  },
  {
    element: document.querySelector('.topfinder'),
    intro: 'This is our math calculator'
  },
  {
    title: 'Farewell!',
    element: document.querySelector('.header_certifiedbtn'),
    intro: 'This is our store for additional math and learning products!'
  }]
}).start();
});
</script>
```

Reproduce this:
Go to https://www.mathcelebrity.com/subjects.php
On the top nav, click Start. This should kick off intro.js tour.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by eliminating JSON and setting up data-title and data-intro directly on the div and anchor elements. Then I called the intro.Js().start() with an Onclick anchor.